# Multiple attributes for a product in magento

Tags: magento

I need to configure a product for multiple attributes in magento.

For example I have product which is a t-shirt. The following attributes need to be configured.

1. Size (Small, Medium, Large, XL and XXL)
2. Color (Gray, White, Green etc)

Though I somehow managed to create these attributes, How could I maintain inventory of a particular t-shirt based on each size and color.

I wanted to handle the stock individually for each size and color. For Example

- T-Shirt 1 - Yellow - XL - 10 nos
- T-Shirt 1 - Yellow - L - 10 nos
- T-Shirt 1 - Black - XL - 10 nos
- T-Shirt 1 - Black - L - 10 nos

Magento should show only the available attributes in inventory for a product.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for what Magento calls a configurable product. Product attributes alone only store information about a product; they don't affect inventory at all. With a configurable product, you'll actually end up with separate simple products for each combination of size and color (known as "associated products"). These won't be visible individually in your store front (unless you want them to), but they will be collected together by a logical "configurable product." You can then track inventory for each individual simple product.

This [documentation from Magento](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/creating-a-configurable-product/) explains in detail how to set up a configurable product. (The directions are actually for their hosted platform, Magento Go, but there will be few or no differences.)

Answer (score 0):

This type of products are called Configurable Product. It was well handled in Magento. Check the below pages to get knowledge about Magento configurable products.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-configurable-product
http://www.magentoadvisor.com/magento-products/complex-magento-products-part-3-configurable-products/

To manage the product color size with auto change product image, use the below extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-views-plus-magento-extension.html
Official Demo: http://demo.temgra.com/index.php/color-views-plus/color-views-plus-magento-extension-magento-plug-in.html